# Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

Tags: hibernate

Here is my configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>


  <!-- Database connection settings -->
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdd_disc?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=GMT</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password">MP18711922</property>

  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

  <!-- SQL dialect -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

  <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <mapping class="org.o7planning.tutorial.hibernate.entities.Artists" />
  <mapping class="org.o7planning.tutorial.hibernate.entities.Disc" />
  <mapping class="org.o7planning.tutorial.hibernate.entities.Song" />

 </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the class to get the SessionFactory :

```
 public class HibernateUtils {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    // Hibernate 5:
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the ServiceRegistry from hibernate.cfg.xml
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()//
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

            // Create a metadata sources using the specified service registry.
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();

            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

I receive the error :

Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

The class doing the main job is :

private static void getTagsFromFile(File f) {

```
    String artist = null;
    String disc = null;
    String song = null;
    Tag tag = null;
    AudioFile af;
    Artists artistInBase = null;
    Disc discInBase = null;
    Song songInBase = null;

     SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
     Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
       try {

           // All the action with DB via Hibernate
           // must be located in one transaction.
           // Start Transaction.            
           session.getTransaction().begin();

           af = AudioFileIO.read(f);
           tag = af.getTag();
           artist = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST);
           artist = artist.replaceAll("'", " ");
           artist = artist.replaceAll("\"", " ");
           disc = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
           disc = disc.replaceAll("'", " ");
           disc = disc.replaceAll("\"", "'");
           song = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);
           song = song.replaceAll("\"", "'");

           int idArtist = -1;
           int idDisc = -1;

           Transaction tx = null;
           try {
               tx = session.beginTransaction();
               String queryAsString = "SELECT artists.name FROM artists WHERE          artists.name LIKE " + "'" + artist + "'";
           Query<Artists> query = session.createQuery(queryAsString);
           List<Artists> artists = query.getResultList();

          if (artists.isEmpty()) {
            artistInBase = new Artists(artist);
            session.save(artistInBase);
            session.flush();
            idArtist = artistInBase.getId();
          }
          else {
            artistInBase = artists.get(0);
            idArtist = artistInBase.getId();
        }
            tx.commit();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    } catch (CannotReadException | IOException | TagException | ReadOnlyFileException
            | InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot parse " + f.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I receive also : Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,109]
Message: La référence à l'entité "characterEncoding" doit se terminer par le délimiteur ';'.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in the maven build life cycle. I used the maven plugin `maven-processor-plugin` as described [here](https://in.relation.to/2009/11/09/hibernate-static-metamodel-generator-annotation-processor/). The maven log contained the following `warning`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:3.3.3:process (process) @ orm-project ---
[INFO] diagnostic: Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.4.12.Final
[WARNING] diagnostic: warning: Unable to parse persistence.xml: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0. Message: null
```

After I switched to maven 3.6.3 and JDK 11 I removed the `maven-processor-plugin` and added the `hibernate-jpamodelgen` to the dependency section. This solved the `warning`. The static metamodel classes are still generated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I understand, My pom.xml have different versions of hibernate. Now It Works.

Comment: Can you please show how you `pom.xml` looks like? I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the suggestion to add `org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen`  to the `<dependencies>` section directly is that you're now including a runtime dependency you do not actually need at runtime. You could set the `<scope>` to `provided`, but that is still wrong conceptually and you might accidentally use a class from that dependency in your source code. A better solution is to add the dependency as an annotation processor to the maven-compiler-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generatedSourcesDirectory>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <annotationProcessorPath>
                    <!-- Note: Use org.hibernate.orm for Hibernate 6+ --> 
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                </annotationProcessorPath>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0. Message: null

can typically come from Hibernate's JPA metamodel annotation processor, when it tries to load/parse the `orm.xml` files (cf. exception handling code in `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.JpaDescriptorParser#loadEntityMappings`). In this case, the exception block is swallowing the root XMLParsingException and displaying only its message, which can be null.
In the case we faced during a code migration from Java 8 to Java 17, the swallowed exception had all the interesting details to help us fix:

> ```
> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
>  - with linked exception:
> [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
> ```

Forgetting to add the JAXB classes on the classpath is a very common mistake when migrating Java 8 projects, but in this case, it was very hard to spot because of the exception swallowing. Adding the missing dependencies solved our case.

It is likely that in your case the root cause is different. But this may give you a hint to solve hit.